# Unable to select CodePipeline as source

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am a Cloud Engineer in a company and I have been assigned to move their resources from their old AWS account to a new one. A lot of things are trivial but I am finding a lot of problems with CodeBuild/CodePipeline and similar, as there is no proper way to export-import.

The main problem I am facing right now is that in the old AWS account (same region), I am able to select CodePipeline as a source for my CodeBuild project. However, I can not do it in the new one. If I check the docs online, there is no reference to CodePipeline being available as a source, but if I check the CLI I can clearly see it is available. I'll put some pics at the end.

Is there any way to create a new project using CodePipeline? It is driving me crazy.

[image: Old AWS Account - Editing the CodeBuild project]

*Old AWS Account - Editing the CodeBuild project*

[image: New AWS Account - Creating a new CodeBuild project]

*New AWS Account - Creating a new CodeBuild project*

[image: Detail of the CLI docs - CODEPIPELINE is available]

*Detail of the CLI docs - CODEPIPELINE is available*

[image: Detail of the web docs - CodePipeline is not available]

*Detail of the web docs - CodePipeline is not available*

Comment: As you noted, you don't do this from console. Have a look at cloudformation, cli or sdk. You can also create empty CP in console, and when you add build stage, you should be able to choose codebuild. In this case, the source should be pre-set for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by myself. You can not create a CodeBuild with CodePipeline as a source directly. To achieve it, you have to run the process with the inverse approach.

Create a CodePipeline project and, once connected a source, you are going to get asked about adding a build step. If you accept it, the new step is going to be a CodeBuild project, using your recently created CodePipeline as a source.